# Find out from where ViewController was opened

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a TableViewController and 2 ways to get there. 
one is a segue(show) from a Viewcontroller that is the root controller of a Navigation Controller, which itself is a tab of my Tab Bar Controller.
second, the tableVC is also a root VC of antoher Navigation Controller, that is also a tab in that Tab Bar Controller. Here is an illustration:
[image: storyboard]

Now i want to check in the `viewDidLoad` if my TableVC, whether it is called by the first or by the second way. How can i find that out?

Comment: Quickly done, but might not be the best way (what about passing a enum/info in the `prepare(forSegue:)` instead), you can use the `self.navigationController` and check how many VC it has, or what's the previous one.

Comment: Just use a var for which screen sends to TableVC in TableVC code with a default 0 . In case of navigation this will be 1 for example. No need to pass it in segue since it will be only "1" when coming from navigation presentation

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to your view controller that indicates where it came from…

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    enum Source {
        case productList, basket
    }

    var source: Source!
}
```

then

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? MyTableViewController {
         vc.source = .productList
    }
}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

very simple just add a var on your viewController which you are going to display , lets assume `var vcOpenedBy = ""`

now when launching this ViewController , just use this var and print whatever you feel comfortable like this

let vc = VcController(nibName:"",bundle:nil)
vc.vcOpenedBy = "NavigationMethod"

and at your segue you can also use this vcOpenedBy 
and use string "SqgueMethod"

now on that viewController in viewDidLoad()
just print this vc . thats it